# * Invalid account: #0 for network: rinkeby - private key too short, expected 32 bytes

Tags: reactjs, solidity

Trying to launch dapp on rinkeby test network using

`npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network rinkeby`

but whenever I've tried launching the contract it comes back with an error saying the private key size is too short when I copy the private key into an environment variable.

When I past the private key straight into the accounts on my module.exports, it throws an error that my private key is too long! regardless if I've appended the 0x prefix before the ${} or not.

hardhat.config.js

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");


const PRIVATE_KEY = "privateKeyjdhsbcidsjhnc"
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  paths: {
    artifacts: './src/artifacts',
  },
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 1337
    },
    rinkeby: {
      url: "https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/_YGPVs4UBSWtFxp-fpynFRcF34oU7WUI",
      accounts: ['0x${process.env.PRIVATE_KEY}']
    }
  },
  solidity: "0.8.4",
};`
```

deploy.js

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
    const Greeter = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Greeter");
    const greeter = await Greeter.deploy("Hello,Hardhat!");

    await greeter.deployed();

    console.log("Greeter deployed to:", greeter.address)
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Must install dotenv file: `npm i dotenv`

1. Check your .env file

   GOERLI_URL_API= d6164sbshdfkjsnkfj6515
   WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY = "hb5154sdhbasd5651sdfsdbf54sf54ss5465F"
2. Check hardhat/config.js

#then require the DOTENV file

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

//add network connection

```
networks: {
    hardhat: {},
     goerli: {
      url: `https://goerli.infura.io/v3/${process.env.GOERLI_URL_API}`,
      accounts: [process.env.WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY.toString()]
    }
  }
```

4.Then Deploy run and build

```
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --show-stack-traces
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly the config file does not regonise your privatekey. If you already put it into your .env file you should check if you already install dotenv and import it to your hardhat.config.ts like bellow:

1- Install `dotenv` dependency
2- import : require('dotenv').config() into your `hardhat.config.ts`

Answer (score 0):

**Change This**

```
  '0x${process.env.PRIVATE_KEY}'
```

**To**

```
`0x${process.env.PRIVATE_KEY}`
```

Answer (score 0):

change `accounts:` in network config section to `account:`
as a result you should have:

```
account: [`{process.env.PRIVATE_KEY}`]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be related to you prepending the private key string in the .env file with a comma.

Instead of:

```
PRIV_KEY = "privatekey123",
```

Do:

```
PRIV_KEY = "privatekey123"
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is only one account so the private key is one.
Make some small change in the line given below,

`accounts: ['0x${process.env.PRIVATE_KEY}']`

instead of writing accounts write only account.ie:

`account: ['0x${process.env.PRIVATE_KEY}']`